# How to send data and a user to a page with a link

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I was told that I can send data and the user to a page without having to use a form. Basically what I have is a page that has products (page is called products) and then an edit button that when I click on it, it takes me to another page called "edit-product" that allows me to see more information (inputs), so that I can edit/add information about that record.

I have been doing this with the form and sending the user there with the form's action attribute. I am wanting to use AJAX with certain elements of the current form on the products page, but I am wanting to delete the form code entirely. (just the form tags).

Here is my code:

```
    $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT `id`,`first`,`last`,`product` FROM users");
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="edit-product">
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'];?>"</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['first'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['last'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['product'];?></td>
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" readonly>
            <input name="first" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['first'];?>">
            <input name="last" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['last'];?>">
            <input name="product" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['product'];?>">
            <td><input name="save" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            <td><div class="delete-class" name="delete" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>
            <td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently, in my edit-product page, I receive the data like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
```

How can I send the user and product data to the edit-products page by changing this or any other code?

```
<td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML localStorage to store values of the form and retrieve them locally once the user gets to the next page/site. No server side data transfer needed.

Example of implementation for localStorage.

```
// Save data to the current local store
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");

// Access some stored data
alert( "username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));
```

You can also use sessionStorage in the same way - but the data will only be stored until you close your browser or nav away from the page.

Comment: I'm not wanting it to be a form from this point on. I will be using a decent amount of AJAX for different functions that are not working with forms very well.

Comment: It dont have to be a form. You can store data from any source on your page in localStorage. You can make AJAX queries as much as needed as well - but if you dont want to have to do AJAX on page change - localStorage is a great alternative (and faster) to handling temporary data storage on the client side.